# NOT IN regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

On an XML value like this

```
<mov><id>1</id><usr>xxxx</usr><tipDown>xxxxx</tipDown><calid>xxxx</calid>....(others tag).....</mov>

<mov><id>2</id><usr>xxxx</usr><tipDown>xxxxx</tipDown><calid>xxxx</calid>....(others tag).....</mov>

<mov><id>3</id><usr>xxxx</usr><tipDown>xxxxx</tipDown><calid>xxxx</calid>....(others tag).....</mov>

.........

<mov><id>123456</id><usr>xxxx</usr><tipDown>xxxxx</tipDown><calid>xxxx</calid>....(others tag).....</mov>
```

I need to find with regex (i use preg_match_all) all the ids that not are in (4,5,34,4567) for example the "NOT IN" it may be just a number or more.

my regex is:

```
<mov>\<id\>([^4]|[^5]|[^34]|[^4567])\</id\>\<usr\>(.*?)\</usr\>\<tipDown\>(.*?)\</tipDown\>\<calid\>(.*?)\</calid\>....\</mov>
```

The `....` are the other tags that I didn't mention in this question because they are a lot.

My Regex doesn't work and I can't make it work

P.S: I can't use a database.

---

**A lot of thks to zx81 and Jack.**

With a merge of they answers, **i found the solution to my specific problem.**

I write the solution and all the explanation

File with a lot of lines like this

```
<mov><id>19</id><usr>50019</usr><tipDown>100019</tipDown><calid>319</calid><pai>3</pai>        <postOrig></postOrig><cat></cat><titulo>este es el titulo</titulo><portExt>.txt</portExt><portRand>3454354</portRand><vis>0</vis>    <sinop>esta es la sin opsis</sinop><txt>texto abierto!<dsf></txt><tipPost>1</tipPost><fecPub>2014-07-09 21:28:24</fecPub><fecAct></fecAct><aniEstr>2012</aniEstr><baj>0</baj><est>1</est><best>1</best><dir>1</dir><form>1</form><titOrig>titulo original</titOrig><youtu>url youtube</youtu><tempo>1</tempo><imdb>url imdb</imdb><denu>0</denu></mov>
```

I need to implement a very easy way to filter this line with dynamic inputs like:
titulo Like %xxxxx%
id=xxxx
id not in (x,x,x,x,x)

but i haven't a database, then i use regex with php

how i do this filters in regex:
not filter anything

```
 <mov>\<id\>(.*?)\</id\>\<usr\>(.*?)\</usr\>\<tipDown\>(.*?)\</tipDown\>\<calid\>(.*?)\</calid\>\<pai\>(.*?)\</pai\>\<postOrig\>(.*?)\</postOrig\>\<cat\>\</cat\>\<titulo\>(.*?)(.*?)\</titulo\>\<portExt\>(.*?)\</portExt\>\<portRand\>(.*?)\</portRand\>\<vis\>0\</vis\>\<sinop\>(.*?)\</sinop\>\<txt\>(.*?)\</txt\>\<tipPost\>(.*?)\</tipPost\>\<fecPub\>(.*?)\</fecPub\>\<fecAct\>(.*?)\</fecAct\>\<aniEstr\>(.*?)\</aniEstr\>\<baj\>(.*?)\</baj\>\<est\>(.*?)\</est\>\<best\>(.*?)\</best\>\<dir\>(.*?)\</dir\>\<form\>(.*?)\</form\>\<titOrig\>(.*?)\</titOrig\>\<youtu\>(.*?)\</youtu\>\<tempo\>(.*?)\</tempo\>\<imdb\>(.*?)\</imdb\>\<denu\>(.*?)\</denu\>\</mov\>#i
```

**filter by: id not in (1,5,34,4567)**

```
#<mov>\<id\>((?!1</id\>|5</id\>|34</id\>|4567</id\>))\d+\</id\>\<usr\>(.*?)\</usr\>\<tipDown\>(.*?)\</tipDown\>\<calid\>(.*?)\</calid\>\<pai\>(.*?)\</pai\>\<postOrig\>(.*?)\</postOrig\>\<cat\>\</cat\>\<titulo\>(.*?)(.*?)\</titulo\>\<portExt\>(.*?)\</portExt\>\<portRand\>(.*?)\</portRand\>\<vis\>0\</vis\>\<sinop\>(.*?)\</sinop\>\<txt\>(.*?)\</txt\>\<tipPost\>(.*?)\</tipPost\>\<fecPub\>(.*?)\</fecPub\>\<fecAct\>(.*?)\</fecAct\>\<aniEstr\>(.*?)\</aniEstr\>\<baj\>(.*?)\</baj\>\<est\>(.*?)\</est\>\<best\>(.*?)\</best\>\<dir\>(.*?)\</dir\>\<form\>(.*?)\</form\>\<titOrig\>(.*?)\</titOrig\>\<youtu\>(.*?)\</youtu\>\<tempo\>(.*?)\</tempo\>\<imdb\>(.*?)\</imdb\>\<denu\>(.*?)\</denu\>\</mov\>#i
```

filter by: id=5

```
#<mov>\<id\>5</id\>\<usr\>(.*?)\</usr\>\<tipDown\>(.*?)\</tipDown\>\<calid\>(.*?)\</calid\>\<pai\>(.*?)\</pai\>\<postOrig\>(.*?)\</postOrig\>\<cat\>\</cat\>\<titulo\>(.*?)(.*?)\</titulo\>\<portExt\>(.*?)\</portExt\>\<portRand\>(.*?)\</portRand\>\<vis\>0\</vis\>\<sinop\>(.*?)\</sinop\>\<txt\>(.*?)\</txt\>\<tipPost\>(.*?)\</tipPost\>\<fecPub\>(.*?)\</fecPub\>\<fecAct\>(.*?)\</fecAct\>\<aniEstr\>(.*?)\</aniEstr\>\<baj\>(.*?)\</baj\>\<est\>(.*?)\</est\>\<best\>(.*?)\</best\>\<dir\>(.*?)\</dir\>\<form\>(.*?)\</form\>\<titOrig\>(.*?)\</titOrig\>\<youtu\>(.*?)\</youtu\>\<tempo\>(.*?)\</tempo\>\<imdb\>(.*?)\</imdb\>\<denu\>(.*?)\</denu\>\</mov\>#i
```

filter by: titulo like '%test%'

```
#<mov>\<id\>5</id\>\<usr\>(.*?)\</usr\>\<tipDown\>(.*?)\</tipDown\>\<calid\>(.*?)\</calid\>\<pai\>(.*?)\</pai\>\<postOrig\>(.*?)\</postOrig\>\<cat\>\</cat\>\<titulo\>(.*?)test(.*?)\</titulo\>\<portExt\>(.*?)\</portExt\>\<portRand\>(.*?)\</portRand\>\<vis\>0\</vis\>\<sinop\>(.*?)\</sinop\>\<txt\>(.*?)\</txt\>\<tipPost\>(.*?)\</tipPost\>\<fecPub\>(.*?)\</fecPub\>\<fecAct\>(.*?)\</fecAct\>\<aniEstr\>(.*?)\</aniEstr\>\<baj\>(.*?)\</baj\>\<est\>(.*?)\</est\>\<best\>(.*?)\</best\>\<dir\>(.*?)\</dir\>\<form\>(.*?)\</form\>\<titOrig\>(.*?)\</titOrig\>\<youtu\>(.*?)\</youtu\>\<tempo\>(.*?)\</tempo\>\<imdb\>(.*?)\</imdb\>\<denu\>(.*?)\</denu\>\</mov\>#i
```

filter by: titulo = 'test'

```
#<mov>\<id\>5</id\>\<usr\>(.*?)\</usr\>\<tipDown\>(.*?)\</tipDown\>\<calid\>(.*?)\</calid\>\<pai\>(.*?)\</pai\>\<postOrig\>(.*?)\</postOrig\>\<cat\>\</cat\>\<titulo\>test\</titulo\>\<portExt\>(.*?)\</portExt\>\<portRand\>(.*?)\</portRand\>\<vis\>0\</vis\>\<sinop\>(.*?)\</sinop\>\<txt\>(.*?)\</txt\>\<tipPost\>(.*?)\</tipPost\>\<fecPub\>(.*?)\</fecPub\>\<fecAct\>(.*?)\</fecAct\>\<aniEstr\>(.*?)\</aniEstr\>\<baj\>(.*?)\</baj\>\<est\>(.*?)\</est\>\<best\>(.*?)\</best\>\<dir\>(.*?)\</dir\>\<form\>(.*?)\</form\>\<titOrig\>(.*?)\</titOrig\>\<youtu\>(.*?)\</youtu\>\<tempo\>(.*?)\</tempo\>\<imdb\>(.*?)\</imdb\>\<denu\>(.*?)\</denu\>\</mov\>#i
```

so go on....

and in PHP my code lokks like

> $regex.=preg_quote("<".MovieFileDao::$NODE_ID.">").           ($search->idPost!=''
>   ? $search->idPost :
>   "(.*?)").preg_quote("");

MovieFileDao::$NODE_ID is declared with the value 'id';

$search is an object that works like a criteria (it have all the properties with every filter)

I show only the filter for id, but i have a filter for all the xml tags.
With regex i can have each filter in a single line of code.

thks

Comment: What if you parse xml with simplexml or DOM XML instead at first place?

Comment: Better way to use php DOM, [getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method

Comment: escape with the backward slash like this `<\/id\>` for the ending tags

Comment: I want to resolve all with regex because is more simple, i dont want to write code. I have resolved all the search with regex very simple, but only this i cant resolve.

Comment: "because is more simple" --- it is so simple so that you cannot do that. Seems reasonable :-D

Comment: Other thing is the xml have more than 100Mb, and with xml parser is not performant

Comment: @Ignacio: "and with xml parser is not performant" --- you have no idea what you are talking about have you? You may parse `xml` files of near to infinite size with proper xml parsers and proper code. Whereas your regex based code presumably reads the whole file into the memory.

Answer (score 1):

**Negative Lookahead**

To say **NOT**, use a negative lookahead before the content to be matched. For instance:

```
(?!(?:4|5|34|4567)</id)\d+
```

The negative lookahead above asserts that what follows is not (4 or 5 or 34) then the literal `</id`.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: `45` will not match then, because it starts with `4`. So "The negative lookahead above asserts that what follows is not (4 or 5 or 34)." -->> "The negative lookahead above asserts that what follows *doesn't start with* (4 or 5 or 34)."

Comment: Hey Ignacio, I had written it to explain the feature—not as a complete solution as I couldn't read your input. Changed it to fit your input, please try it now.  :)

Comment: @zerkms When I posted this, the input was unreadable. It was not meant to fully solve the question, but to illustrate the feature, in full awareness of the limitations (lack of delimiter etc). Now that the input is readable, I have edited  the answer. In my understanding of the words, the phrasing `what follows is not` is accurate. For me "What follows" does not mean "What follows until the end of the string"... Just what follows. For instance on a freeway, when you say that what follows your car is a VW, you don't mean that the VW is the only car behind you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use the wonderful `DOMDocument` for this and assuming each match is on their own line you could use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) instead:

```
$lines = file('test.xml');
$matches = preg_grep('~<id>(?:4|5|34|4567)</id>~', $lines, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

The last flag only returns the lines that do NOT match the expression.

Using an XML parser (untested):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml('test.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//mov') as $element) {
    $id = $element->getElementsByTagName('id')->items(0)->textContent;
    // filter here
}
```

If the XML files are particularly big, I would recommend using a [pull parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) instead.

Comment: Every time you answer with a regex in an `xml` tagged question - a kitten dies (+1 anyway :-D)

Comment: @zerkms I agree; I've added a more responsible solution :)